# create a general command to select certain observations in a data frame with thousand observations

Tags: r

I tried to search an answer to my question but I didn't find it; if there is already an answer please write the link.

I have a data frame with something about 50k observations; the data frame contains observations from 2008 to 2014 and it derives from a national survey. Each year some families have already been interviewd and others are new. 
I need to filter the data frame in order to eliminate the families that appear only one time.
For exmaple:

```
df[1:7,]

      NQUEST NORD ANNO
1      173    1   2008
2      375    1   2008
3      465    1   2008
4      465    2   2008
5      465    3   2008
6      465    4   2008
7      629    1   2008

s[13703:13710,]

      NQUEST NORD ANNO
82137    173    1 2010
82138    375    1 2010
82139    465    1 2010
82140    465    2 2010
82141    465    3 2010
82142    465    4 2010
82143    732    1 2010
82144    732    2 2010
```

Nquest is the number of the family and nord is the componenet of the family. In this case I want to eliminate the family number 629 and 732.

I tried to create a dummy that is equal to one if the observation appear more than one time and zero otherwise, but the problem was to create a general command right for each observation (without writing the number 173 and so on, remember the data frame contains 50k observations).

Thank you

Comment: Yes, but it refers to two different components of the family (for example 1 father, 2 mother).

Comment: how many data.frames do you have (seems you have 2 ?)

Comment: or `df[with(df, ave(ANNO, NQUEST, NORD, FUN = length))>1,]` Also, good eye @Cath!

Comment: What is the desired output? You want to remove the rows that contain 629 or 732 in them? Or you want these numbers? Would `library(data.table) ; setDT(df)[ , if(.N > 1L) .SD, by = .(NQUEST, NORD)]` work for you?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

should not this be simple as intersect(unique(df$NQUEST), unique(s$NQUEST)) gives you the NQUEST s common to both and you want to filter out the ones that appear only in one of them.

```
common.NQUEST <- intersect(unique(df$NQUEST), unique(s$NQUEST))
df.filtered <- df[df$NQUEST %in% common.NQUEST,]
s.filtered <- s[s$NQUEST %in% common.NQUEST,]
```

Answer (score 2):

Not the most efficient I guess but here is a way to know which family you don't want:

```
names(which(rowSums(table(df$NQUEST, df$ANNO)!=0)==1))
#[1] "629" "732"
```

*Explanation:*
`table` permits to get the `NQUEST` according to `ANNO`, then you filter out the families that are present only in one year, and get their names.

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(NQUEST = c(173L, 375L, 465L, 465L, 465L, 465L, 
629L, 173L, 375L, 465L, 465L, 465L, 465L, 732L, 732L), NORD = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L), ANNO = c(2008L, 
2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L)), .Names = c("NQUEST", "NORD", 
"ANNO"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", 
"5", "6", "7", "82137", "82138", "82139", "82140", "82141", "82142", 
"82143", "82144"))
```

**NB:** If you have two data.frames, you can just check which of the second data.frame (recent entries) are not in the first data.frame : `which(!s$NQUEST %in% unique(df$NQUEST))`...

Comment: Maybe also `library(data.table) ; setDT(df)[ , if(uniqueN(NORD) == .N) NQUEST, by = NQUEST]$V1` or something that *doesn't* involve `apply`...

Comment: tl;dr. Maybe also `unique(setDT(df)[ , if(.N == 1L) NQUEST, by = .(NQUEST, NORD)]$V1)` just for fun. And YES, I'm watching you....

Comment: @DavidArenburg new version, not using `apply` but using only `base R` :-)

Comment: @Cath try adding a new record in the dataframe `c(732, 1, 2008)`. This should still return the same output as it is in different year. (2008). Isn't it?

Comment: @RonakShah nope, to me, it should only return `629` (as my solution returns) because it would mean family `732` is present in 2 different years (2010 and 2008) and so should stay in the df (basing myself on *"Each year some families have already been interviewd and others are new. I need to filter the data frame in order to eliminate the families that appear only one time"*)

Comment: @RonakShah actually both your solutions agree with me ;-)

Answer (score 1):

use count function in the plyr package

```
   library(plyr)

    tmp <- as.data.frame(count(df,vars = c("NQUEST","NORD")))
    tmp <- tmp[tmp$freq > 1,]
```

count function in plyr gives you n-way frequency  for all pairs. So you can filter in those items with more than one frequency.

Output

```
   NQUEST NORD freq
1    173    1    2
2    375    1    2
3    465    1    2
4    465    2    2
5    465    3    2
6    465    4    2
```

Comment: In addition, the results I get with `plyr::count` are not correct.

Comment: @Sotos read the question properly. Infact it should not stay as it has different `NORD` value

Comment: sorry, my bad...I thought it SHOULD stay because of different NORD

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution with dplyr. I put the filtering into a function. You can put more than one dataframe as arguments into the function, it will be converted to a single dataframe and then be filtered. Explanations are in the code. I hope this helps. (I also provided an example with more rows).

```
# Create function to filter
# you can provide several dataframes (with same columns) to the ... argument
filt_nqest <- function(...){

  library(dplyr)

  # put dataframes into a list of dataframes
  list_df <- list(...)

  # bind the dataframes together to one dataframe
  df <- bind_rows(list_df)

  df %>%
    select(NQEST,ANNO) %>% # selecting the two columns from the dataframe
    unique(.) %>% # reduces the dataframe to the unique combinations of family number and year
    count(NQEST) %>% # count the number of years, families were questioned
    filter(n > 1) -> famques # filter out families that were qestioned only once

  df %>% 
    filter(NQEST %in% famques$NQEST) -> df_filtered # use new variable to filter

  # return filtered dataframe
  return(df_filtered)

} # End of function  


# Create test data
NQEST <- c(173,375,465,465,465,465,732,732)
NORD <- c(1,1,1,2,3,4,1,2)
ANNO <- c(rep(2010,times=8))

s <- cbind.data.frame(NQEST,NORD,ANNO,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

NQEST <- c(173,375,465,465,465,465,629)
NORD <- c(1,1,1,2,3,4,1)
ANNO <- c(rep(2008,times=7))

df <- cbind.data.frame(NQEST,NORD,ANNO,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

# TEST with small example
filt_nqest(df,s) -> df_test


# test data from the dplyr package for use as a big example
require(Lahman)
df <- as.data.frame(Batting[1:100000,],stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
df %>% rename(NQEST=playerID, ANNO=yearID) -> df

s <- as.data.frame(Batting[100001:200000,],stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
s %>% rename(NQEST=playerID, ANNO=yearID) -> s

df_test <- filt_nqest(df,s)
```